# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Кто нибудь может объяснить постановку этой запятой? Или это все-таки ошибка?

Для предотвращения контакта рабочей среды со штоком 1, опорой штока 6 и корпусом 7(,) шток дополнительно покрывается футеровкой 2 до места вторичного уплотнения.

Также и здесь:

Для обеспечения высокой чистоты поворотных затворов, (…) предлагает возможность изготовления затвора в производственном помещении класса чистоты 10 000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка. Никаких причин для постановки запятой нет. Это не оборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: И во втором примере тоже нет.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных предложениях распространенные обстоятельственные обороты входят в основное сообщение и не обособляются.